# Plot doesn't show up in figure window

Tags: matlab, plot

I am using the built-in Matlab "plot" function to make many plots from a lot of data. Every single one of them works except for one. What's even more strange is that the one that doesn't work essentially has identical code to others that do work.

Here's the part of the code that's supposed to plot in a separate figure:

```
f = figure;
ax = subplot(1,1,1, 'Position',[0.1 0.16 0.8 0.815]);
grid(ax, 'on')
hold(ax, 'on')
plot(ax, x, y)
```

Where x is a 100x1 double matrix of all the same number and y is a 100x1 uint32 matrix of all the same number, both of which are previously defined.

The axes come up in the figure just fine, but as soon as I try to plot anything the axes disappear and it becomes just a blank figure window.

This person had a similar problem, but the solution still didn't work for me (even in debug mode):

http://www.mathworks.fr/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/286813

The only thing I can possibly think of that's different about this data set versus others that I've successfully plotted is that x and y are repetitive... could this have anything to do with it? Does Matlab have a "limit" to how many points it can plot at one time?

Any idea why this is happening to me or how to fix it? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: So basically you are plotting one single 2D point 100 times?

Comment: Yes. I know it sounds stupid, but first of all it's just test data (a placeholder, essentially) and second this general code is what I use for all of the plots, so if there's a problem with it I need to know now to deal with the ripple effect.

Comment: And your other plotting code is **identical**  ?

Comment: Correct. The only difference is the data that gets passed to it.

Comment: Can you add the code that initialises x & y so that others can see if they can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't... the data is generated in a C++ function and then passed to Matlab, where it goes through so many functions before being passed to the plots that there's no way I could post all of it. I'm currently tracing the data backwards to try to find the bug in it because I think it's the problem. I'm also going to try generating new data and plotting that. I will post an answer if either of these methods work. Thank you both for your contributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was just an issue of bad data. The numbers Matlab was reading in were too small and so couldn't be plotted. Regenerating some better test data solved my problem. Thank you to those who offered suggestions!